# VBA Code fails to prevent WrapText

Tags: vba, excel

The following Code prevents the data inputed in the cell from being Wrapped...

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Value = Application.Evaluate("CONCATENATE(L1,N1)")
        .WrapText = False
    End With
End With
```

This works just the way I want it to. However, this one has a problem with `.WrapText = False`

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Range("L1").Value2
        .WrapText = False
    End With
End With
```

If I had to guess, I am missing some sort of `.Value` line to put in before the `.WrapText = False`. I just don't know what that `.Value` should be to make it work. If someone has a solution, could you also explain how you know what `.Value` to put?

Comment: What cells exactly do you want to set the wraptext to??? Your changes are only applied to "A2" and "B2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you avoid assigning values in the line you define the with block:

```
    'this gets probably B2 only
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 

        'this sets the value of B2 with the value of L1
        .Value = ActiveSheet.Range("L1").Value2
        .WrapText = False
    End With
```

If you wanted to take the entire column instead of just B2:

```
    With ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
```

Comment: Why do we want to avoid assigning values? Would there be another way to use `.WrapText = False` if we didn't assign a value?

Comment: In the with line, I would avoid it, because the type of `Value2` (can be an integer, a string or an array) is different from the type of `Cells.....Offset` (which is a `Range`). Maybe VBA automatically handles this, but just in case, I would not use it in my code. As you can see, I moved the same assignment one line below, inside the block, so it's still there. By the way, you have two with blocks....the code may get confused when choosing between one of them.

Comment: okay that makes sense and I will do more research to get a better understanding. The code seems to work in the sense that it isn't returning an error. However, it is being returned as a blank cell. Could this be because the value is a date and needs to be formatted as a date or?

Comment: I made another change. Since you had two with blocks, the code could be taking `.Range("L1")` from either the Active sheet of the cell you selected. I made it only one with block.